# Connecting with HTTPS to Azure Worker Role fails when listening from executable

Tags: azure, ssl, web-applications, https, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Worker Role and the worker role simply launches another executable and keeps it running. The executable is a web application that handles traffic on port 80(http) and port 443(https). The SSL certificate being used is embedded within this executable web app.

The web app works on HTTP but not on HTTPS.
I have both endpoints configured:

```xml
<Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="tcp" port="443" localPort="443" />
</Endpoints>
```

And I have to use protocol tcp as the certificate and SSL decryption is handles within the executable itself. But the traffic never makes it to the executable.

When navigating to the Web App via HTTPS, Chrome indicates the following error:

> Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Is there something else I need to configure in Azure to allow this traffic through?

Comment: That should be all you need to configure on the Azure side.  When you RDP to the Azure VM what do you see?  If you run netstat do you see your app listening on both 80 and 443?  What do you see in netmon when a client tries to connect?

Comment: Why not `protocol="https"`?

Comment: I can't do protocol="https" because it wont compile without a certificate. But the certificate is distributed with the launching .exe and not the worker role. I ended up using a virtual machine and opening the ports and it has worked better.

Comment: A VM is probably the better way to go here IMHO.